# How to set projection variables in Jena

Tags: sparql, jena

I am programtically constructing a SELECT query in Jena but I am not able to add the projection variables. I am using the method `addResultVar` from the class `Query` but when serialising the query, the output query select all variables.

for example, I am adding a projection variable like q

```
 Op op = new OpBGP(bp) ;
q.addResultVar("name");
```

still, when serializing the query, the only problem is that the query generated is like `"SELECT * ...."` and not `"SELECT ?name"`

How to add projection variables properly in Jena ?

Comment: Can show more of the code please. The first line uses the algebra and then you have the query object suddenly. That's confusing. Without seeing the whole code it's just guessing what you did, but I guess you converted from algebra to query. Please call `q.setQueryResultStar(false)` which might have been set in the code before by some operations which we don't see

Comment: yes you are right, that was the problem, thanks

Comment: @AKSW, can you help in this question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879509/comparing-two-sparql-queries-in-jena