# Comparing two SPARQL queries in Jena

Tags: sparql, jena

I want to know whether two SPARQL queries are logically equivalent, for e.g. suppose I have two queries as follows, how can I know if they are equivalent ?

```
String query1= "SELECT ?name where { <http://www.example.com/P500> a <http://www.example.com/Parking>; " +
                "<http://www.example.com/name> ?name .}";

        String query2= "SELECT ?name where { <http://www.example.com/P500> <http://www.example.com/name> ?name;" +
                " a <http://www.example.com/Parking> .}";
```

The codes below doesn't perform a logical comparison:

```
System.out.println("Compare query pattern");
        System.out.println(q1.getQueryPattern().equalTo(q2.getQueryPattern(),null));

        Op qop1 = Algebra.compile(q1) ;
        Op qop2 = Algebra.compile(q2) ;

        System.out.println("Compare query operator");
        System.out.println(qop1.equalTo(qop2,null));
```

Comment: Maybe it works if you compare the two optimized algebra expressions? But I guess, at least the variable names have to be the same, otherwise you have to solve an isomorphism problem

Comment: I just updated the code, i did try this but no success

Comment: The triple patterns are in a different order. Equality, or queries (Query.equals) or algebra is not "logically equivalent" but based on syntactic equivalence.

Comment: @AndyS, yes I put the triples in different order on purpose to see whether logical equivalence can be verified